# Encrypting password for c3p0 ComboPooledDataSource

Tags: apache, hibernate, jakarta-ee, tomcat, c3p0

I currently have a server.xml configuration which has the following in it

```
<Resource auth="Container"
    description="DB Connection"
    driverClass="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    maxPoolSize="40"
    minPoolSize="2"
    aquireIncrement="1"
    name="jdbc/FOOBAR"
    user="foo"
    password="bar"
    factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
    type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    jdbcUrl="path:to:db:port:db" />
```

I have a requirement to no longer allow the username/password to be in clear text in the server.xml file for obvious reasons.

I've  read a bit online and came across [How to Secure Tomcat Database Passwords for Java](http://java.sys-con.com/node/393364/print)
 [Encrypt username and password for JNDI in Tomcat Server.xml](http://scribblejava.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/encrypt-username-and-password-for-jndi-in-tomcat-server-xml/) and many other pages; however, I'm a bit stuck.

I first looked at extendind the BasicDataSourceFactory - but it seems that can't occur due to my using c3p0 CombinedPooledDataSource.  I then looked at trying to create a c3p0 datasource wrapper by implementing PooledDataSource, Serializable and Referenceable but that didn't work either.

I read I could move the authentication to the server side by making auth="Container" => auth="Application".  However, I'm not sure of how to implemet the rest of the pieces with my using Hibernate.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this will not be a high-security solution.

But an easy way around this is to make use of the fact that c3p0's "password" property is just a configurable c3p0 property, which can be set in a wide-variety of ways. So, you could create a c3p0.properties file and/or a c3p0-config.xml file, and set the password there. Alternatively, you could make sure that a System property c3p0.password is set when you run the JVM.

If you'll have multiple DataSources with different passwords, you'll need to use c3p0's named config feature, which means a c3p0-config.xml file.

c3p0 config (both c3p0.properties and c3p0-config.xml) files can be stuck at the top-level of a jar file in your application's effective CLASSPATH. (With tomcat, you have to be careful about distinctions between the web-app specific ClassLoader and more widely shared locations.) So, you can have your password embedded in a compressed jar file rather than a plain text file. Obviously, this is not secure: plaintext is just an "unzip" away. But it would prevent the password from being casually greppable and such.

Please see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuration_files

Good luck!